# C# Query SQL different datetime format to dataGridview

Tags: sql-server, winforms, t-sql

I get an error return by t-sql because of different type of datetime format store in database.
Datatime format user input will be like this **'18-03-2019'**

**Below are two example table of my DB :**

```
Staff   Id      No   Hex     Ref    sex      update_date_time
1234    4943    01  0x20    SN002   male    2019-03-18 10:31:09.000
1234    4943    01  0x30    SN001   female  2019-03-18 10:32:09.000
1234    4943    01  0x10    SN003   female  2019-03-18 10:33:09.000
1234    4943    01  0x20    SN003   female  2012-06-18 10:34:09.000
```

**Below is the query user input**:

This sql will only get the result of three row from the table above

```
 SELECT Staff,Id,No,Hex,Ref,sex, update_date_time FROM workers WHERE update_date_time = CONVERT(date,'18-03-2019',103)
```

**Solution i have try:**

Some information come from this [link](https://tableplus.io/blog/2018/09/ms-sql-server-how-to-get-date-only-from-datetime-value.html). The result i want is date will input by user and the way i do won't get all the date from the sql table.
The query below will end out with error.

```
SELECT  SELECT Staff,Id,No,Hex,Ref,sex, update_date_time FROM workers WHERE update_date_time = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),103)
```

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted
>   in an out-of-range value

Comment: Thats because you've converted to a date which then won't match on the time component i.e. `2012-06-18 10:34:09.000` != `2012-06-18 00:00:00.000`

Comment: @DaleBurrell if all the datetime end up with different time such as
 2012-06-18 10:34:09.000 , 2012-06-18 10:35:09.000, 2012-06-18 10:38:09.000,2012-06-18 10:34:09.000 is there any solution for this?

Comment: If you only care about the date, you should remove the time component when you save it to the database. Otherwise use @Squirrels solution

Comment: Convert table data to date as well. `... WHERE convert(date, update_date_time) = CONVERT(date,'18-03-2019',103)`

Comment: @DaleBurrell i have take Squirrels answer thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it is because your `update_date_time` contains a time component. A normal solution to that is to use `>=` and `<`. You use greater or equal to a date and less than the day after.

```
SELECT Staff,Id,No,Hex,Ref,sex, update_date_time 
FROM   workers 
WHERE  update_date_time >= '2019-03-18'
AND    update_date_time <  '2019-03-19'
```

OR

```
DECLARE @input DATE = '2019-03-18'

SELECT Staff,Id,No,Hex,Ref,sex, update_date_time 
FROM   workers 
WHERE  update_date_time >= @input
AND    update_date_time <  DATEADD(DAY, 1, @input)
```

of-course if you don't care about *performance* and wants and easier query, convert the column `update_date_time` to DATE before compare

```
SELECT Staff,Id,No,Hex,Ref,sex, update_date_time 
FROM   workers 
WHERE  CONVERT(DATE, update_date_time) = @input
```

Comment: update_date_time will get the string from textbox that user input with your solution will need to update the 'update_date_time < ' all the time

Comment: i have update my question,  i forget to list the datetime user input